# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to make my pandas DataFrame group data together. Currently, if you input data, for example: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 - it will come out like this:

```html
   column1  column2
1:     2
2:     2
3:     1
```

I would like it to just group the data if they have the same value in column2 and for this example, just show 2 : 2, meaning 2 of the numbers inserted were both inserted twice, so we will just count that. Here is my current code:

```html
from collections import Counter
import time
filename = input("Enter name to save this file as:\n\n")
print("Your file will be saved as: " + filename + ".csv\n\n")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("Please enter information")
contents = []

def amount():
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()

        except EOFError:
            break
        contents.append(line)

    return

amount()

count = Counter(contents)
print(count)

import pandas as pd

d = count
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns =['column1', 'column2']
df.sort_values(by=['column2'].value_counts())
df.to_csv(filename + ".csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in this using value_counts() in Pandas, not sure if it'll work for you!

```
values = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['values'])

res = df['values'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index().sort_values('index')

# renaming the columns
res.columns = ['Values', 'Count']

display(res)
```